# Spark Streaming filter condition inside foreach - NullPointerException

Tags: scala, foreach, spark-streaming

We have a stream data for which i have some master information in a HBase table. For every row i need to lookup to the HBase master table and get some profile information. My code is something like this

```
val con             = new setContext(hadoopHome,sparkMaster)
val l_sparkcontext  = con.getSparkContext
val l_hivecontext   = con.getHiveContext

val topicname       = "events"
val ssc             = new StreamingContext(l_sparkcontext, Seconds(30))
val eventsStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,"xxx.xxx.142.xxx:2181","receive_rest_events",Map(topicname.toString -> 10))
println("Kafka Stream for receiving Events.." )

val profile_data = l_hivecontext.sql("select gender, income, age, riid from hbase_customer_profile")
profile_data.foreach(println)
val tabBC = l_sparkcontext.broadcast(profile_data)

eventsStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    rdd.foreach(record => {
    val subs_profile_rows = tabBC.value
    val Rows = record._2.split(rowDelim)
    Rows.foreach(row => {
      val values = row.split(colDelim)
      val riid = values(1).toInt
      val cond = "riid = " + riid
      println("Condition : ", cond)
      val enriched_events = subs_profile_rows.filter(cond)
    }) // End of Rows
  }) // End of RDD
}) // End of Events Stream
```

Unfortunately i always hit on NPE on the filter. I had followed few questions and answers here to broadcast values across worker nodes, but nothing is helping. Can someone help please.

regards

Bala

Comment: Check whether you're using a value that cannot be serialized.

Comment: I am not sure if profile_data should be created inside the foreach and that is what is not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Your context usage looks a bit fishy...  To me, it looks like you are creating two separate contexts (one spark, one for spark-streaming) and then trying to share a broadcast variable between those contexts (that will not work).

We have some code we wrote around this that was similar.  Here are the videos showing how we did it in Splice Machine (Open Source) in case you are interested.  I will try to find the code or have someone else post it for you.

http://community.splicemachine.com/splice-machine-tutorial-video-configuring-kafka-feed-splice-machine-part/

http://community.splicemachine.com/splice-machine-tutorial-video-configuring-kafka-feed-splice-machine-ii/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks John. I will look into the Video. Requirement is to read profile information from HBase table for the data that comes off DStream. I got forEachPartition as well (will post the changed code as next comment), but that gives me different errors. I shall wait for the code if you can get it please. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Due to space restrictions, i will have to split my code into 2 posts. - Start       class setContext(argHadoopHome: String, argSparkMaster: String) {
  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir",argHadoopHome)
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(argSparkMaster);
  conf.setAppName("Evts");

  private val l_valSparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
  private val l_hiveContext = new HiveContext(l_valSparkContext)

  def getSparkContext = l_valSparkContext
  def getHiveContext  = l_hiveContext
  def getconfContext =  conf
}

Comment: object receiveEvents {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    var rD  = "\r\n"
    var cD  = ","
    var sM  = "spark://nm2:7077"
    var ip    = "nm2:2181"
    var hadoopHome    = "/home/.."
    val con             = new setContext(ip,sM)
    val l_sparkcontext  = con.getSparkContext
    val topicname       = "evt"
    val ssc             = new StreamingContext(l_sparkcontext, Seconds(9))
    val eventsStream  = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,"nm2:2181","rcv",Map(topicname.toString -> 2))
    val profile_data = w_hivecontext.sql("select gender, income, age from hb_cust_pro")

Comment: eventsStream.foreachRDD(rdd =>{
rdd.foreachPartition(records =>{
val wc = new setContext(hH,sM)  // connections in worker
val w_hivecontext = wc.getHiveContext   // serialization
records.foreach(rec =>{ // Recs
val Rows = rec._2.split(rD) // as Rows
  Rows.foreach(row =>{ // Row
    val values = row.split(cD) // Splitting to Columns
    val riid = values(1).toInt // for filter
    val cond = "riid="+riid
    profile_data.filter(cond) // Lazy loading-filter condition
    profile_data.foreach(println)
  }) //Rows
}) //RDD
}) //Part
}) //Str
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination() } }

Comment: Thanks once again, the code won't work exactly as pasted above. Due to space constraints i had to remove few things. But it will give the entire picture. Thank You!